# Convert UTF-8 hexadecimal to regular character

Tags: c#, .net, encoding

Does anyone know how to convert a string in C# that has UTF-8 hexadecimal characters in it to a regular characters.?

**For example**

hell%c3%b3  to hello

**Chart**

```
UTF-8      ASCII     TECKEN   Flattened
%c3%b3     %f3       ò        o
```

There are many UTF-8 hexadecimals I need to convert is there a way to do this with a built in method in .NET?

Comment: Where did this string come from?

Comment: Just from experience, I'd recommend trimming the string before starting to work on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called URL encoding and can be undone with

```
using System.Web;
HttpUtility.UrlDecode("hell%c3%b3");
```

This gives `helló`, but probably that's what you wanted.

The second part, removing the diacritics, is not so simple, see [How do I remove diacritics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249087/how-do-i-remove-diacritics-accents-from-a-string-in-net) here on SO.